# To click the button automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code i have grid view in which i have a textbox and a button if i enter a textbox and on leaving textbox it should click the button automatically.Pls help me to do this.

```
 function js_function() {
            $("#ButtonAdd").trigger("click");
        }


<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity"  onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);"    runat="server" Height="20px" Width="150px" onblur="js_function();"   > </asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>                                   
                                </asp:TemplateField>


 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" ItemStyle-Width="100px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete()" >Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <FooterTemplate>                                     
                                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"  class="button" Text="Add New" />                                                            
                                   </FooterTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: since your button is within gridview, you wont get the selector as #ButtonAdd, rather you have to use the class as $(".button").click()

Comment: you code should work, please check button id after generating DOM structure. it should be `ButtonAdd` only.

Comment: @D.T. but it closes the page

Comment: you want to do it on server side or using client side JQuery?

Comment: didn't got you, closes the page means? If you are refering to a post back then you can hide the button by using style="display:none", add another html button without runat="server" and fire the click event of the html button which will inturn fire the server button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the id is changing on client side due to asp button try attaching the event with this selector -
`$( "input[id*='ButtonAdd']" ).click();`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the button real ID in the html is not ButtonAdd, but something more complex generated by ASP. Try to obtain button real ID by <%= ButtonAdd.ClientID %>

Comment: if i set button to visible false it is not calling if it true it calls i want to call if button visible is false

Comment: I see, its because of browser. It is not possible to 'click' hidden button. You can unhide it -> click -> hide it. It should work. Or set buttons position to fixed and left value for example -5000. It causes the button is out of page but 'visible' a clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one of your buttons, you could add ClientIDMode="Static" to your button to make sure that ID of the control is not polluted by master page names and such (if you have a control that can repeat itself for example, it will add $parentcontrolid_ChildControlId_ChildControlIndex_ before the id you have supplied.
This would give you the following button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"  class="button" Text="Add New" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Or you could add a wildcard to your jquery selector to find ANYTHING_ButtonAdd with the following selector:

```
$('input[id*='ButtonAdd']).click();
```

click() will do the same thing as trigger('click') in most cases (in your case, it will do the same thing :P)
trigger('click') is said to be faster at runtime, but click() is easier to read/write, so use the one you like the most.